# Where to define DbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I´m starting a asp.net (5) mvc project and I had create a DBContext for my application in the Models directory.

This context is injected in the controllers using it constructor, like this:

```
private AppContext db;

public CidsController(AppContext context)
{
    db = context;
}
```

Inside the controller actions, I use this dbcontext for query over my dbSets:

```
 var itens = from p in db.Posts
             select p;
```

Now, I want to move all querys to the models classes (Post.cs in this case), so I need to know:

1. Are the models classes used for this?
2. If yes, how to access dbContext from there ?

Thanks.

Comment: There's already a lot written about this. Search the web for "asp.net mvc application architecture", additionally with "multi-tier". In (very) short: no, you don't put database logic in your viewmodels, that belongs in a data layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, models aren't used for this, they just contain the data that travels from the controller to the view and (through HTTP) back to the controller.

That means you don't need `DbContext` in your models. The controller is responsible (possibly delegated to a business and database layer) for the retrieval of the data. This is a very common principal in the [MVC design pattern](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/127624/what-is-mvc-really).